# Serial Voting Bug?

Tags: support, bug

**Disclaimer**: This is not a rant nor am trying to get the points back.

Today I noticed an alert which says Serial Voting reversed. I am quite familiar with this concept and **I am totally in sync** why this is necessary.

My assumption of anything that involves "Serial" whether it is "Serial voting", "Serial killing", "Serial lying", "Serial plagiarism" etc means that there is at least 2 of such incidents to make it a serial. A single instance can never qualify to be a "Serial Something".

Is my understanding incorrect?

I can understand that 15th Dec votes can fall under "Serial voting" but 13th and 14th December? How does a single vote on separate date considered a "Serial vote"?

[image]

Comment: I mean... there's no reason to think the other actions weren't against not your account.

Comment: Sorry kevin. I do not understand. Your comment doesn't answer my question... `How does a single vote on separate date considered a "Serial vote"?`

Comment: People often try to avoid getting caught by casting votes across multiple accounts, not just one. When this occurs, *all* such votes are reversed.

Comment: Ah! Ok. I now understand! Feel free to put that as an answer? And if that is the correct answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Also... If what you say is correct then it should also be mentioned in [Why do I have a reputation change on my reputation page that says "voting corrected"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) So people like me who take time out to read documentation do not waste mine and others time :)