# Explain why "voting corrected" may only include one vote in the Help Center article

Tags: feature-request, reputation, help-center, serial-voting

Today I asked question [Serial Voting Bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427557/serial-voting-bug) which was **correctly** closed as a duplicate of [-10 Serial voting was reversed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423202/10-serial-voting-was-reversed).

I consider myself a guy who reads documentation before asking a question. Basically I love to RTFM.

Before asking the question, obviously, I checked the link provided in the reversal alert "reversal -10 Voting corrected ([learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed))".

[image: snapshot of preceding alert)]

And guess what? I was confused. I also tried looking for similar questions but did not come across any posts. [@ErikA](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7296893/erik-a) was able to find that one for me.

**Please add that explanation to that documentation.**

[@KevinB](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b) summed it up nicely:

> People often try to avoid getting caught by casting votes across multiple accounts, not just one. When this occurs, all such votes are reversed.

The first sentence in the paragraph below comes close to my request but in no way can one think it describes this particular scenario. If this scenario had been mentioned then I wouldn't have asked that question today.

> Most commonly, when a single user continually votes (up or down) on
> many of your posts within a short period of time, the system considers
> these votes to be invalid and removes them. This could happen for a
> variety of reasons, such as when a user finds another user’s answer
> great, and visits their profile to upvote many of their posts, or when
> a user gets into an argument with another user and downvotes their
> posts indiscriminately in revenge. No matter the cause, this sort of
> voting targeted at a person is not permitted - always remember to vote
> for the post, not the person who wrote it.

If we add this then we can prevent any such questions in the future from the people who like to RTFM.

Comment: I understand your confusion, as in the case votes were cast by the same person using more than one account, at least two votes would be rolled back.  However I recall reports that were confirmed of a bug that allowed two upvotes from the same account, as a kind of timing issue.  I suspect the automatic correction in that case appears as you have observed, one of the two votes is disallowed.  I'll look for those reports.

Comment: @hardmath: Were you able to find it?

Comment: Have a look at the last bullet point in [this Answer on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/379864/155839), which links to an example.  It's not entirely what I remembered, but relevant I think.